# Does a MySQL User needs to be added to MySQL "system"?

Tags: mysql, sql

Does a MySQL User needs to be added to MySQL "system"?

I am learning MySQL basics but this question just popped out. Here is why:

```
:~$ mysql -u johndoe
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 50
Server version: 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.   

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SELECT User();
+-------------------+
| User()            |
+-------------------+
| johndoe@localhost |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> quit
Bye
```

of course I didn't set up a user named johndoe, but it seems that I am able to enter mysql with any username. I'm not saying I'll see any database at all, as it may not have been set any databases where johndoe, for example, could do something.

So my question finally is: Is this true or I am seen it the wrong way?

Comment: If you can log in mysql with random users that mean you are running your server with `--skip-grant-tables`

Comment: Not really. You can see @SelloLekgothoane answer, or follow these links: [function_current-user](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user), [function_user](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_user) and [account-activity-auditing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/account-activity-auditing.html).

Comment: You can follow [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/default-privileges.html) too, very elucidative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, MySQL connected you as an anonymous user (''@localhost) because the user "johndoe@localhost" does not exist. run "SELECT CURRENT_USER()" and you'l see what I mean, also, if you check the user table in the mysql database you'l find a row where host='localhost' and user=''.

Comment: Miguel mind marking the question as answered and giving Sello the points he deserves for the answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know I needed to do that. Now I think it is all right: question marked as answered and Sello got his points.

Comment: When you mark the question as answered, the answer's author gets 15 points, and you get 2 points.